# Insert text in middle of String (link)

Tags: java, regex

I am getting a URL from a message that is in the form `https://example.com/eUjKSv`, however I need to insert a "tag" `/raw/` in between `.com/` and `eUjKSv`.
I was wondering what would be the easiest way to do it, currently I have a very "hacky" way to achieve it, `new URL("https://example.com/raw" + new URL(link).getPath())`, I know it's pretty awful and only works if I know exactly the URL. Any suggestions on how to make this better? I thought about regex but couldn't think of a good one to capture it.

Comment: i think with regex that capture "https://example.com" and "/eUjKSv" as 2 part then add /raw in the second part will be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either the [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class or the [`URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class. They both work for this.

```java
URL baseUrl = new URL("https://example.com/eUjKSv");
URL rawUrl = new URL(baseUrl, "/raw" + baseUrl.getPath());
System.out.println("baseUrl = " + baseUrl);
System.out.println("rawUrl = " + rawUrl);
```

```java
URI baseUri = new URI("https://example.com/eUjKSv");
URI rawUri = baseUri.resolve("/raw" + baseUri.getPath());
System.out.println("baseUri = " + baseUri);
System.out.println("rawUri = " + rawUri);
```

*Output*

```
baseUrl = https://example.com/eUjKSv
rawUrl = https://example.com/raw/eUjKSv
```

```
baseUri = https://example.com/eUjKSv
rawUri = https://example.com/raw/eUjKSv
```